# gtsummary - is there a way to put footnote at the very bottom without a row?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm a bit new to R and tinkering with gtsummary package to create a table containing descriptive statistics for my M.A. thesis. I was able to create one for my current purposes. However I want the footnote to have no dedicated row (as circled in the picture) but rather at the bottom of the table because of the format requirements of institute I'm afilitated with. I searched a lot, but couldn't find an earlier post that addressed this issue. Is there a way to accomplish this in gtsummmary? I'm also open to the suggestions of alternative (preferably, beginner-friendly) packages that can do this. Here's the code and output :

[image: Picture]

```
tbl <- 
# iterate over these two statistics
c("{mean}","{sd}","{min}","{max}") %>%
 # build tbl_summary using each of the stats
 map(
  ~l2 %>% 
  select(AoA, Reading, Writing, Speaking, Listening, AVG_PROF ) %>% 
  tbl_summary(type = c(Reading = "continuous", Writing = "continuous", Speaking = 
  "continuous", Listening = "continuous"),
   statistic = all_continuous() ~ .x, label = list(AVG_PROF ~ "Overall" , AoA ~ "AOA"),  
              missing = "no"
  ) 
  ) %>%
 # merge the two tables together
 tbl_merge() %>%
 modify_caption("**Table 1. Linguistic Background of the L2 participants**<br><br>")  %>%
 modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA) %>%
 modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA) %>%
 modify_header(list(stat_0_1 ~ "**Mean**", stat_0_2 ~ "**SD**", stat_0_3 ~ "**Min**", stat_0_4 
 ~ "**Max**")) %>%
modify_caption("<div style='text-align: left'>Table 1. Linguistic Background of the L2 
participants<br><br></div>") %>%
modify_table_styling(
columns = label,
label == "AOA",
footnote = "Age of Acquisition of English"
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, if that's `html` output, then I would consider setting up custom `css`, like:

```r
---
title: ""
author: ""
css: "mycss.css"
---
```

and in `mycss.css` file something like:

```
table.gt_table {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
```

which removes the bottom border.

[image]

In pdf output the footnotes are below `longtable`

[image]

which is consistent with https://github.com/rstudio/gt/blob/master/R/utils_render_latex.R ~ 467 line, where footnotes are wrapped within `minipage` environment.

As a proposal for consideration - have you had look on [kableExtra](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/)?